# How to get users running processes without it's username in it?

Tags: ps

I'm trying to write all users and their running processes in file using: `ps -r -U username -o pid,command,user > up.txt`
But I don't need commands that contains users name in it.
How can I filter commands by their name?

Example

```
22312 ps -ls                       username
16411 ps -r -U username -o pid,com username
```

I need to get only 22312 row

Answer (score 0):

to be honstly the answer would be it depends
quick and short on debian:

```sh
ps | cut -c -6
```

since it depends on the usage (context) , the used distribution and atm of posting this answer, of information on the question